# Let $f:\mathbb{C}-\{0\}\mapsto \mathbb{C}$ a holomorphic function, how to determine all the functions which satisfies :

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}-\{0\}\mapsto \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function, 
and satisfies 
$$|f(z)|\leq|z|^2+\frac{1}{|z|^{1/2}}$$ 
for $z$ near $0$

how to determine all such functions ?

Comment: For $z$ near $0$, or for all $z \neq 0$? In either case you might want to look at $zf(z)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Write $f(z)$ as a Laurent series expansion about $z=0$. Write each coefficient $a_n$ as a Cauchy integral and try to give an estimate for them.

Comment: Thank you , I'll have a try

Answer (score 0):

Well I asked this question to my,teacher , here is his answer :

If $f$ is analytic or have a removable singularity at $0$, then it is bounded , of course satisfies the inequality.

Next consider $zf(z)$, one can find that it equals to $0$ ,as $z$ tends to $z$, thus the constant term of the Taylor expansion of $zf(z)$ is $0$, thus $0$ is a removeable singularity of $f$.